# How to apply a postsharp aspect to just methods defined in child classes of a given class?

Tags: c#, aop, postsharp, aspect, aspects

Can I specify that a PostSharp aspect will be applied just to all public methods of child classes of a given class?

I mean, I have `ClassA` and want that an `OnMethodBoundaryAspect` be applied just to public methods defined in classes that inherited from the `ClassA`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `AttributeInheritance` property of `MulticastAttribute` to control that behavior.

- `MulticastInheritance.None` is the default behavior. Aspect is not inherited by derived classes.
- `MulticastInheritance.Strict` makes derived classes inherit the aspect on base class members, i.e. on overridden methods.
- `MulticastInheritance.Multicast` makes derived classes to completely inherit the aspect, i.e. as if you have specified the aspect on the derived class.

Then, you need to use `AttributeTargetMemberAttributes` of `MulticastAttribute` to specify on which members the attribute should be applied. In your case this would be `AttributeTargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public`.

Last, you need to force PostSharp not to apply the attribute to the base class itself, you may use `AttributeExclude` property on another attribute instance to disable the aspect on specific occasions.

So, "just to all public methods of child classes of a given class" would be satisfied by the following:

```
[MyAspect(AttributeInheritance = MulticastInheritance.Multicast, AttributeTargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public)]
[MyAspect(AttributeExclude = true)]
public class ClassA
{
    //...
}
```

Note that this is compile-time behavior and you need to run PostSharp on all projects that are deriving from the base class in order for it to work as intended. If you derived from the class in a project not enhanced by PostSharp, no aspect behavior will be inherited.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Daniel, but what at least I misunderstand what you said, with none of those options I get what I want: apply the attribute to *"just to public methods defined in classes that inherited from" a given class*

Comment: @gsc-frank The question was not entirely clear. I have updated my answer to match it's intended meaning more closely (hopefully).